CSS Stacking Groups of Divs, But Getting Them Aligned On The Right
The magenta and cyan divs are wrong. They should be aligned to the right of the encompassing yellow div. I have put in right: 0px; on the magenta and cyan divs, but this does not work as expected.


<body style="width:100%; height: 100%; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0; overflow: hidden; background:#000000; font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 5vh; right: 5px; z-index: 100; background-color:#FF0; margin: 3px 5px;">
    <div style="right: 0px; background-color: #F0F; width: 10vh; height: 10vh; margin: 0vh 0vh 1vh 0vh;"></div>
    <div style="right: 0px; background-color: #0FF; width: 10vh; height: 10vh; margin: 0vh 0vh 1vh 0vh;"></div>
    <div>
      <div style="right: 0px;">
        <div style="float: right; background-color: #F00; width: 7vh; height: 7vh; margin: 0vh 0vh 1vh 0vh;"></div>
        <div style="float: right; background-color: #0F0; width: 7vh; height: 7vh; margin: 0vh 1vh 1vh 0vh;"></div>
      </div>
      <div style="right: 0px;">
        <div style="float: right; background-color: #00F; width: 7vh; height: 7vh; margin: 0vh 0vh 1vh 0vh;"></div>
        <div style="float: right; background-color: #FFF; width: 7vh; height: 7vh; margin: 0vh 1vh 1vh 0vh;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



Also I have heard floats are cumbersome.
How do I clear all the floats so any divs below are not affected?

style="right: 0px;" won't do anything unless you set a position other than the default. You can also look into flexbox or grid instead of using floats

These type of layout can easy be implemented from Grid / Flex System and in future it will be helpful for you make it responsive too.

Don’t use floats, use flexbox or grid. This snippet uses nested flexboxes.


body {
  background: black;
}

.d1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 1em;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1vh;
  /* in a column-oriented flexbox, "align-items" controls the horizontal position, so "start" means align left and "end" means align right. */
  align-items: end;
}  

.d2 {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1vh;
}

.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

.magenta, .cyan {
  width: 10vh;
}

.red, .lime, .blue, .white {
  width: 7vh;
}

.magenta {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.cyan {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.lime {
  background-color: lime;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}
<body>
  <div class="d1">
    <div class="square magenta"></div>
    <div class="square cyan"></div>
    <div class="d2">
        <div class="square lime"></div>
        <div class="square red"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d2">
        <div class="square white"></div>
        <div class="square blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



